# use php variable as sql field laravel Elqouent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I want to use the variable $soptions as a fieldname on my query but im just getting error 500 with this code, please help

```
    $Input=Input::all();
    $makethis=Input::flash();
    $soptions=Input::get('soptions');

    $items = Gamefarm::where('roost_hen', '=',Input::get('sex'))
                        ->where('". $soptions ."', 'LIKE',"%et%")
                        ->paginate(6);

    return View::make('gamefarms/index',compact('items','makethis'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `->where($soptions, 'LIKE', "%et%")`

Comment: Thank you so much! The heck the answer is to simple

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `soptions` as string, not as a variable.

Your statement says to select the field `soptions` from the DB Table, but, you want the value of the variable `$soptions`.

Change

```
$soptions=Input::get('soptions');
```

To

```
$soptions=Input::get($soptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $Input=Input::all();
$makethis=Input::flash();
$soptions=Input::get('soptions');

var_dump($soptions);
```

// here you can known type of $soptions

```
$items = Gamefarm::where('roost_hen', '=',Input::get('sex'))
                    ->where('". $soptions ."', 'LIKE',"%et%")
                    ->paginate(6);

return View::make('gamefarms/index',compact('items','makethis'));
```